# The iPhone app closes like an error when I go to home screen and comeback

Tags: ios, xcode5, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to write a game for iPhone using SpriteKit. Almost everything is fine and runs as I expect but the only problem is when I was testing it to see what happens if I go to home screen and comeback to the app, I noticed every time that I come back to the app it shows it in the last state and then suddenly closes the app after a second.
My app is using sounds and I noticed that if I remove the playing sound actions, everything is fine. The sound actions is this:

```
SKAction * playClickSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"buttonClick.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];
[self runAction:playClickSound];
```

Interestingly, if my app runs but doesn't get the point to run this action, everything works fine again when I go back and forth between app and home screen. Funny thing is it seems to be OK on the simulator and this problem only happens when I run code on my iPod touch.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? http://jamesaddyman.com/spritekit-sounds-background-obscure-crash/

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is adding disabling `AVAudioSession` in the app delegates when the app resigns active and again enabling it when it becomes active again.
This line should be added to the top of AppDelegate.m file:

```
@import AVFoundation;
```

And `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];` and `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];` must be added to the functions as following:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

Special thanks to @0x7fffffff for his/her help.

Answer (score -1):

This is what happens when your app gets terminated in the background due to memory pressure. Unfortunately, because of iOS 7's new graphical "features" this happens more frequently now especially on older devices.

You should consider implementing state restoration for your app.